# Convert array to rest argument

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

How do I make `chain` use a spread-parameter (`...chain`) instead of an array?

```
let newData,
    newArgs,
    chain = function (data, myargs) {
        if (myargs.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        newData = myargs[0](data);

        myargs.splice(0, 1);
        newArgs = myargs;
        // newargs === array
        chain(newData, newArgs);
    },
    add1 = (num) => {
        return num + 1;
    };
```

When I call the function, I have to do it like this: `chain(5, [add1, add1, add1])`.

But I want: `chain(5, add1, add1, add1)`

The problem is, that `newArgs` (the function parameter inside of the recursion) is converted into an array after the first function call.

https://jsfiddle.net/btx5sfwh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use [rest arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) the array when calling the function recursively

```js
let newData,
  newArgs,
  chain = (data, ...myargs) => {
    if (myargs.length === 0) {
      return data;
    } else {
      newData = myargs[0](data);
      myargs.splice(0, 1);
      newArgs = myargs;
      chain(newData, ...newArgs);
    }
  },
  add1 = (num) => {
    return num + 1;
  };


chain(5, add1, add1, add1);

console.log(newData); // 8
```

Comment: But this way, I cannot pass `...myargs` as a rest-argument again, **inside** the function again.

Comment: aah I see, so when I use `...myargs` instead of `myargs`, it gets converted automatically?

Comment: Yes, the **rest** of the arguments are converted to an array. To pass that array  as regular arguments when calling the function again, you **spread** them.

Comment: thanks man, I wasn't aware you could use spread inside a function call.

Comment: @TomM: Even if you couldn't, you could always use `.apply`: `chain.apply(null, [newData].concat(newArgs))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write `chain` in a much nicer way

```js
const chain = (x, f, ...fs) =>
  f === undefined
    ? x
    : chain (f (x), ...fs)
    
const add1 = x =>
  x + 1
    
console.log (chain (5, add1, add1, add1)) // 8
console.log (chain (5))                   // 5
```

Rest parameter and spread arguments are somewhat expensive tho - we generally want to limit our dependency on these, but we don't want to sacrifice the API we want either.

Don't worry, there's an even higher-level way to think about this problem. We can preserve the variadic API but avoid the costly spread argument.

```js
const chain = (x, ...fs) =>
  fs.reduce((x, f) => f (x), x)

const add1 = x =>
  x + 1

console.log (chain (5, add1, add1, add1)) // 8
console.log (chain (5))                   // 5
```